# Running thin restart after rails code deploy, constant 502 bad gateway errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, thin

Problem:  All requests made while thin is restarting, result in 502 Bad Gateway Errors.

When I deploy code changes to my server, I have to restart thin to have the new changes take effect.  My thin config yml looks like this:

```
chdir: /var/www/appname
servers: 6
environment: production
onebyone: true
wait: 30
no-epoll: true
address: 0.0.0.0
port: 3000
timeout: 30
log: log/thin.log
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 512
require: []
daemonize: true
```

My understanding was that the property "onebyone" would make sure that at least 1 server is always available to respond to requests.  However, what happens is that any requests made until all servers are finished restarting, will result in 502 Bad Gateway errors or 504 Gateway Time-out.  How can I ensure that my requests are always handled properly after I push new code to production?

**UPDATE**

thin logs show this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:572:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:572:in `start_server'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/tcp_server.rb:16:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:53:in `block in start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/thin:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
```

I'm restarting with `sudo thin -C /etc/thin/appname.yaml restart`

It appears that what's happening is that thin is trying to listen on port 3000, but the previous thin process is still running on that port?  Why would this happen?

Comment: Are you using a web server in front of thin (e.g. nginx)?

Comment: Yea, I'm using nginx.  I think what is happening is that nginx isn't able to talk to thin, because something funky is happening during the thin restart.

Answer (score 1):

When Thin stops, it deletes the socket file through while it communicates with Nginx, and then recreates it on a successful start. Even with Thin stopped, NGinx is still listening for web requests. If a request is made to Nginx at that point, it will result in an error like you mention. It just means that Thin was not able to start properly, or bind to a socket in your case. It could mean that you are try to stop and start too fast.

A cap task like this *should* work fine.

```
task :restart do
  sudo "bundle exec thin restart -C thin.yml"
end
```

Is this still a problem when the `onebyone` is removed ?

I also found this article to very useful for implementing rolling restarts with Thin and Capistrano - http://pointatstar.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/rolling-restart-for-thin-cluster-via-capistrano/

Personally, I've been using Unicorn as it has rolling restart built in. It was covered in a RailsCast - http://railscasts.com/episodes/373-zero-downtime-deployment

Comment: Yes, it's still a problem with oneoneby removed.  I'm not using Capistrano now, and was hoping to not have to add any further gems to my setup for the sake of simplicity.  Unicorn sounds interesting -- would it be a replacement for thin or a supplement to thin?

Comment: Its an awesome replacement for Thin. I've left Thin for Unicorn a while ago. The biggest feature is that you can ask Unicorn to spawn multiple processes and it will manage/housekeep it. In Thin, you have to manage each Thin process your self via God, Monit etc. NGinx + Unicorn is the default choice these days.

Comment: For debugging sake, just put a sleep of 5 seconds between stop and start and see. I'm guessing its trying to start before its completely stopped. I have seen this before, and I remember fixing it by starting/stoppingin another way. Can you add that detail to your question.

Comment: Cool, at least I have a good alternative if i cant get this fixed.  Edited question to add the info you requested.  I thought that using 'restart' instead of 'stop' and 'start' would be the only way to ensure that an instance of thin would always be available to serve requests.